# PHP, MySQL - delete from multiple tables with join

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I have 3 tables:
**categories, posts and comments**.

**categories and posts** are connected via **categories.id_category = posts.category_id** and **posts and comments** are connected via **posts.id_post = comments.post_id**.

When I delete **category**, I want also to delete all the posts related to that category and all comments related to that posts. Can this be done in one query?

Comment: The best way would be to create your tables with ``foreign keys`` and use ``references`` in tables -> called ``referential integrity``. Take a look at http://dev.mysql.com/tech-resources/articles/mysql-enforcing-foreign-keys.html Maybe this is the right thing for you

Comment: Yes. It can. With or without referential integrity

Comment: And if you do not want `foreign key` and want to do other way use trigger to handle it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

MySQL InnoDB databases support the FOREIGN KEY constraint with ON DELETE CASCADE clause. With this specifications, related dependent table rows will be deleted when doing a DELETE on the referred table.

This is an example:

```
CREATE TABLE categories (
    id_category int unsigned not null primary key,
    ...
);
CREATE TABLE posts (
    id_post int unsigned not null primary key,
    category_id int unsigned not null,
    ...
    FOREIGN KEY (category_id) REFERENCES categories (id_category)
       ON DELETE CASCADE
);
CREATE TABLE comments (
    post_id int unsigned not null,
    ...
    FOREIGN KEY (post_id) REFERENCES posts (id_post)
       ON DELETE CASCADE
);
```

Here you can find documentation about the use of foreign keys in MySQL:
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/create-table-foreign-keys.html

Comment: So, the logic is that I only need to delete category and all the posts and comments will be auto deleted?

Comment: Yes, you can do a single DELETE on the categories table and all referenced rows will be deleted too. I clarified this in the answer.

Comment: Cool :). Can I alter my tables or I need to create new ones in order for the foreign key to work?

Comment: You can alter tables, for example:
`ALTER TABLE posts ADD INDEX (category_id);` to add the index, then
`ALTER TABLE posts ADD FOREIGN KEY (category_id) REFERENCES categories (
id
) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE NO ACTION ;`